# Use of `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`, `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo`, and `BeEquivalentTo`

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I am working with fluent assertions in my unit tests, however the use of `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`, `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo`, and `BeEquivalentTo` is unclear.

For example; all the following statements pass so the functions appear equivalent.

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() { "james", "wood" };
List<string> b = new List<string>() { "james", "wood" };

a.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(b);
a.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(b);
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);
```

Why should I use one rather than the another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ShouldBeEquivalentTo` and `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo` are the same and will do a recursive structural comparison. But since the behavior is highly configurable, some of the options support using property expressions to include or exclude certain members. However, the `T` in the expression refers to the type of the root object (`List<string>`) when `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` is used, and `string` if `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo` is used. The former acts on the entire object whereas the latter acts on `IEnumerable<T>`.

`Should().BeEquivalentTo()` is a much simpler implementation which will just do an order-insensitive comparison using `Equals`. This method will be removed in the next breaking change (v5.x).

Comment: The changes in V5 described in https://continuousimprover.com/2018/02/fluent-assertions-50-best-unit-test.html#upgrading-tips

Answer (score -3):

As concept, a list is viewed as a single unit. Thus, from the readability point of view, choosing one of your options, the single valid call is "a.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(b);".

Regarding others, they are obscure.

The plural form "ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo" is applied when comparing 2 collections of elements. I think, one would argue that we are comparing these group of strings (A) with these group of strings (B). What happened here, the group of strings was gathered as a whole single concept under a List data structure type. Thus, I would say it is wrong to use this call.

The last form implies 2 things. First, object "a" should be transformed into something. The name "Should" doesn't communicate anything. Afterwards, the result should be compared if it is equivalent with a list object "b". Logically, one should compare 2 objects of same type. There is no need for an additional transformation.

When reading code, I would prefer the following format:

A list "A" is equivalent with another list "B".

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() { "james", "wood" };
List<string> b = new List<string>() { "james", "wood" };

//creating "IsEquivalentTo" method
bool listsAreEqual = a.IsEquivalentTo(b);

//creating "IsEqualTo" method
listsAreEqual = a.IsEqualTo(b);

//overloading operator ==
listsAreEqual = (a == b);
```

Comment: I'm confused by your answer, the functions I asked about are functions from the third party assertion frame work Fluent Assertions (https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions).